# React+Redux - Uncaught Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I tried to create a simple react-redux-ajax working example, following [Reddit API tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html), but I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?
```

The error is thrown by:

`dispatch(fetchProducts(this.props));` in **App.jsx**

**index.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import { createDevTools, persistState} from 'redux-devtools';

import DevTools from './DevTools.jsx';
import App from './App.jsx';
import rootReducer from './reducers.js';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        DevTools.instrument(),
        applyMiddleware(
            thunkMiddleware,
            loggerMiddleware
        ),

        // Lets you write ?debug_session=<name> in address bar to persist debug sessions
        persistState(window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/))
    )
}

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>, document.getElementsByClassName('products')[0]);
```

Comment: Please try to narrow your provided code down to areas that you think are relevant - it's difficult to read through an entire app in a question. As for your issue, it looks like you're importing redux-thunk as a named import, when it should be a default import, e.g. `import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'`.

Comment: @ShaneCavaliere thanks for response. I edited my question and tried to reduce code in my question (I am new in redux). I changed  `thunkMiddleware` as a default import, but it didn't help.

Comment: Middleware needs to be the 3rd argument to `createStore`, not the 4th - per the documentation: `createStore(reducer, [initialState], [enhancer])` - Try removing the dev tools injection.

Comment: @lux You are right, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot to compose your enhancers, the third argument to `createStore` must be a function so you need to `compose` all your enhancers to provide a unique `enhancer` :

**index.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import { createDevTools, persistState} from 'redux-devtools';

import DevTools from './DevTools.jsx';
import App from './App.jsx';
import rootReducer from './reducers.js';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(
                thunkMiddleware,
                loggerMiddleware
            ),
            DevTools.instrument(),
            persistState(window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/))
        )
    )
}

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>, document.getElementsByClassName('products')[0]);
```

[Redux DevTool doc](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/blob/master/docs/Walkthrough.md)